# Connection reset by peer: socket write error in restTemplate with large JSON request body

Tags: java, json, connection, resttemplate, large-data

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

**request have one field with 8Lac+ characters** i.e. large JSON request body

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "url": Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

As the above code is working for small JSON data, I'm not getting why it is not working for large JSON data.

Comment: You've probably exceeded an upload size limit at the server.